# Кириллица в доменном имени сайта

Tags: url, домен, кириллица

Можно-ли сделать адрес сайта на русском языке?
Если да, то можно совместить русский язык с английским?
Вот так: siteaдресс.com ?

Comment: Адрес сайта "на русском" определенно можно сделать.

Comment: Кириллицей только домены в зоне ".рф". И только кириллицей. Мешать с латиницей уже нельзя - это защита от подделок схожих букв c-с, e-е и т.д.

Comment: @Mrak нет, не только, кириллические домены спокойно живут и в других зонах: `.com`, `.net`, `.ru`, и другие. Подробнее [смотрите IDN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN)

Comment: Не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо огромное всем!

Answer (score 2):

А вы попробуйте проверить сомнительный домен. Например на [reg.ru](https://www.reg.ru/)

> .com — общий домен верхнего уровня для коммерческих организаций (сейчас используется без ограничений).
>   Доменное имя может содержать от 2 до 63 символов.
>   Доменное имя должно начинаться и заканчиваться буквой латинского алфавита или цифрой. Промежуточными символами могут быть буквы, цифры или дефис.

Дополню про запрет смешивания кириллицы с латиницей
Доменное имя в домене .РФ должно состоять из собственного обозначения,
уникального в пределах домена верхнего уровня, и символов «.рф».
Собственное обозначение должно отвечать следующим техническим требованиям:

1) содержать не менее двух символов;

2) содержать такое количество символов, чтобы представление обозначения в
кодировке Punycode содержало не более 63 символов;

3) начинаться и заканчиваться буквой или цифрой;

4) не содержать символов, отличных от букв, цифр и дефиса (допустимыми буквами
являются буквы русского алфавита, включая букву «ё»; прописные и строчные
буквы не различаются).

https://cctld.ru/files/pdf/docs/rules_ru-rf.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно, вы можете сделать **кириллический домен** и использовать его. При регистрации кириллического домена мешать буквы кириллического и латинского алфавита нельзя, хостер Вам этого не даст сделать.

Правда если его использовать не как зеркало на основной сайт, то работа с ним будет усложнена конвертацией [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) с вытекающими из этого последствиями.